# Corda flow change does not work with corda OS 4.0

Tags: corda

I performed below steps .

1. I have changed corda flow and removed this line , builder.setTimeWindow(serviceHub.clock.instant(), 30.seconds)
2. Now performed "gradle jar" command to build only jar and because of that created new corda app jar . e.g.  old version "abc-1.1.jar" to  new version "abc-1.2.jar"
3. Now I deployed new "abc-1.2.jar" in cordapps folder for node and restarted the node.
4. I am UNABLE to update old corda transactions and any update action on corda transaciton results into below error and corda node gets down after some time.

[INFO ] 2019-07-11T17:56:43,227Z [pool-12-thread-1] statemachine.FlowMonitor. - 
 Flow with id 90613d6f-be78-41bd-98e1-33a756c28808 has been waiting for 97904 seconds to receive messages from parties [O=BigCorporation, L=New York, C=US].

5. I am getting this issue and after 5 mins corda nodes stops saying heap space issue although i have given 6gb for norda node.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your flow is a pair of Initiator and Responder where the Responder runs on a different node. You might have updated the jar on the first node, but forgot to update it on the responder node so when your initiator is opening a FlowSession with the responder; the responder doesn't have the class for the Responding flow and Initiator is getting stuck waiting for a response. Check the logs (inside `cordapps/log`) of your responding node.